# Axios POST request: Content-type is set, but inside spring it's empty

Tags: javascript, java, spring

I'm sending video as POST request using `Axios` with `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'`, but inside Spring I see the following error:

```
"[org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type '' not supported]"
```

The Axios code :

```
async function uploadPost() {
    const type = 'video/mp4';

    let data = new FormData();
    const videoUri = imagePreview;

    data =
      ('video',
      {
        name: 'mobile-video-upload',
        type,
        videoUri,
      });
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/post/upload',
      body: data,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

The function inside Spring :

```
   @CrossOrigin
   @ResponseBody
   @RequestMapping(value = "/post/upload",  method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
   public String create(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it working with Postman rest client ?

Comment: @Sambit im using iphone simulator, so i dont know how really...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Spring code to be correct, please try with minor changes with Axios.

```
const axios = require('axios')
const qs = require('querystring')
....... other code .....

const config = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }
}

axios.post(url, qs.stringify(requestBody), config)
  .then((result) => {
    // Do somthing
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // Do somthing
  })
```